# Get-S3Object only returns list of data with no -Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I am using S3 Powershell api (Get-S3Object) to retrieve files from S3. I've only been able to get it to work when not using a -Key or file path to a specific folder.

For instance, when I run the below in Powershell ISE, it returns all files/folders inside that bucket (runs how I expect it to):

```
$s3AccessKey = 'MyAccessKey'
$s3SecretKey = 'MySecretKey'
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $s3AccessKey -SecretKey $s3SecretKey
Get-S3Object -BucketName "myBucket"
```

However, when I run the below in powershell, it runs successfully with no errors but returns nothing:

```
$s3AccessKey = 'MyAccessKey'
$s3SecretKey = 'MySecretKey'
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $s3AccessKey -SecretKey $s3SecretKey
Get-S3Object -BucketName "myBucket" -Key "myPathToFolder"
```

What's stranger is that if I directly call out a specific file in the -Key section it returns a list of data about the object (how I expect it to run):

```
$s3AccessKey = 'MyAccessKey'
$s3SecretKey = 'MySecretKey'
$Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $s3AccessKey -SecretKey $s3SecretKey
Get-S3Object -BucketName "myBucket" -Key "myPathToFolder/specificFile.pdf"
```

So it only works on the root bucket and when I directly call out a file but not any other directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, S3 does not have the concept of a folder structure, even if the AWS Console might trick you to think it has. Everything is a key-value pair in S3. Getting this out of the way, the `-Key` parameter expects an exact key (or a full path if we think about it in a folder structure way) and it will return information about a single object or nothing ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3Object.html)).

What you are looking for is to get all the files which have the same prefix. For that you could use the `-Prefix` or `-KeyPrefix` argument like this:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName "myBucket" -KeyPrefix "myPathToFolder"
```

Comment: Ervin - I forgot to update you but this solved my problem. You nailed it!. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Happy to hear. Please consider accepting my answer in case you found it helpful.